# Grabbing all matching items in Shell output to list

Tags: bash, shell

When I run the following command on shell `adb devices`. It shows me a bunch of devices like

```
List of devices attached
10.16.95.35:5555    device
10.16.95.36:5555    offline
10.16.95.37:5555    device
10.16.95.38:5555    device
10.16.95.39:5555    device
10.16.95.40:5555    device
10.16.95.41:5555    offline
10.16.95.42:5555    device
10.16.95.43:5555    device
10.16.95.44:5555    device
```

I am trying to get only offline deviceIps as a list. So the output in this case I desire is `10.16.95.36,10.16.95.41`

I was able to get just offline listed as through `adb devices | grep offline`

```
10.16.95.36:5555    offline
10.16.95.41:5555    offline
```

but i do not know how to process it further to get `10.16.95.36,10.16.95.41`.

Comment: `adb devices | awk -F: '/offline/ { print $1 }'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cut` with colon as `-d` delimiter to get the first `-f` field.

Then use `paste` with `-s` and `-d`

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on jordanm's comment,

```
$: adb devices|awk -F: 'BEGIN{c=""} /offline/{printf "%s%s",c,$1;c=","} END{printf "\n"}' 
10.16.95.36,10.16.95.41
```

That should only get the lines you want, and format the way you asked.